# How to combine multiple matrix frames into one using R?

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I am manipulating my genomic data using R but I am encountering some problems. Although I could solve my problems on my own, I think that there is a more efficient way to solve it.

I have three matrices with two columns indicating that one is a gene name and the other is cancer information, and I want to combine them into one data frame.

Here are my matrices:

```
result0
tp53   c1
apc    c2

result1
tp53   d1
col2a1 d2

result2
tp53   e1
wt1    e2
```

and what I want to do is to combine the three matrices into one by adding two columns as shown in figure below.

```
combined result
tp53   c1 d1 e1
apc    c2
col2a1 d2
wt1    e2
```

By combining duplicated rows into a single row and adding two additional columns, I can merge different data sets into a new one containing all the results.
How can I do it by using R language? I need to solve this problem on matrices with a large number of rows.

Comment: read _in detail_ the help page `?merge.data.frame`

Comment: [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) function only takes two arguments to merge. Since you have three matrices, you have to call [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) to cumulatively merge:

```
m1 <- matrix(c('tp53','apc','c1','c2'),2);
m2 <- matrix(c('tp53','col2a1','d1','d2'),2);
m3 <- matrix(c('tp53','wt1','e1','e2'),2);
m <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,1,all=T),list(m1,m2,m3));
m;
##       V1 V2.x V2.y   V2
## 1    apc   c2 <NA> <NA>
## 2   tp53   c1   d1   e1
## 3 col2a1 <NA>   d2 <NA>
## 4    wt1 <NA> <NA>   e2
```

It is not the design of `merge()` to combine non-key columns, thus, as you can see, the c1/c2/d1/d2/e1/e2 values are still separated into separate (non-leftmost) columns in the merged object. You can solve this with another line of code (or you could combine the two lines into one, since `m` is used only once on the RHS of this second line of code):

```
m <- as.data.frame(t(apply(m,1,function(x) na.omit(x)[1:length(x)])));
m;
##       V1 V2   V3   V4
## 1    apc c2 <NA> <NA>
## 2   tp53 c1   d1   e1
## 3 col2a1 d2 <NA> <NA>
## 4    wt1 e2 <NA> <NA>
```

You may notice that the row order of `m` does not follow the order in which key values occurred in the input matrices. I'm not sure exactly why this happened; it appears that `merge()` can place unmatched rows (e.g. `apc`) before matched rows (e.g. `tp53`). A guaranteed row order is not part of the contract of `merge()`. In any case, you can fix this with the following (row names can be fixed up afterward as well, if necessary, via [`row.names()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html)/[`rownames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html)/[`dimnames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dimnames.html)):

```
m[match(m[,1],unique(c(m1[,1],m2[,1],m3[,1]))),];
##       V1 V2   V3   V4
## 2   tp53 c1   d1   e1
## 1    apc c2 <NA> <NA>
## 3 col2a1 d2 <NA> <NA>
## 4    wt1 e2 <NA> <NA>
```

Notes:

- I haven't bothered messing with column names anywhere, since you haven't specified column names in your question. If necessary, you can set column names after-the-fact using a call to [`names()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html)/[`setNames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html)/[`colnames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html)/[`dimnames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dimnames.html).
- Funnily enough, although `merge()` accepts matrix inputs, it always spits out a data.frame, and although [`apply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) accepts data.frame inputs, it always spits out a matrix. I've added a final call to [`as.data.frame()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.data.frame.html) in the second line of code because you've specified you want a data.frame as the output, but you can remove that call to get a matrix as the final result.